# Three edges in a path

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

> Given a finite connected graph, let $A$ be a set of edges such that each edge in $A$ is not part of a cycle. Suppose that no path contains all edges in $A$. Must it be true that for some three edges in $A$, no path contains all the three edges?

This is equivalent to showing that if every subset of three edges in $A$ is contained in a path, then there is a path containing all edges in $A$. I’ve tried doing induction, but even going from three to four doesn’t seem obvious. Each set of edges $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ and $\{e_2,e_3,e_4\}$ has a path containing it, but other edges maybe used in both of these paths in various orders.

Comment: How should I be interpreting the condition "are not part of a cycle"?  If, say, it means "there is no cycle in $G$ containing all edges in $A$" then we can always cover all of $A$ by a path unless $A$ is the whole cycle, so I'm wondering if you have something else in mind.

Comment: @BenBarber Sorry, I now realize that my original question wasn't clear. Please see the new version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend $A$ to a spanning tree $T$ of $G$, which is possible greedily for any acyclic subgraph of a connected graph.  Since $A$ cannot be covered by a single path, there is a vertex $v$ such that at least $3$ of the branches of $T$ at $v$ lead to components $C_1, C_2, C_3$ containing edges $a_1, a_2, a_3$ of $A$.  We claim that these edges cannot be covered by a single path.

Indeed, suppose there were such a path $P$.  Fix an orientation of $P$ and label each $a_i$ according to whether $P$ traverses $a_i$ towards or away from $v$.  By reversing the orientation and relabelling if necessary we may assume that $P$ traverses $a_1$ and $a_2$ away from $v$.  But then there must be a path from $C_1$ to the start point of $a_2$ 
not passing through $a_1$, which would place $a_1$ on a cycle in $G$, a contradiction.

Comment: If the graph consists of four vertices $a,b,c,d$ with edges $(a,b),(a,c),(a,d)$, then it looks like your vertex $v$ doesn't exist.

Comment: @user136454, I've fixed that and another infelicity in the original answer.

Comment: How do you formally prove that $v$ exists though? I don't think it's obvious from "since $A$ cannot be covered by a single path".

Comment: Throw away everything except the minimal subtree of $T$ containing $A$.  If it isn't a path then it has a vertex of degree at least $3$, which we can take to be $v$.